# VBA Script To Scroll Through PivotTable Report Filter

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a repot filter in my PivotTable for which I wish to select a value and then run a macro. Is there any script that will cycle through all the values in the filter? To use an example: I have January, February and March as options to choose in the report filter, and wish the script to select January and then run a macro, then select February and run a macro and finally select March and run a macro.

I can't make the script select the value of 'January', 'February' etc given that - in the work I am doing rather than the example - I am not limited to the 12 months of the year, but to several hundred variables each of which could change from time to time.

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
Sub CycleReportItems()
Dim pvt As Excel.PivotTable
Dim pvtPageField As Excel.PivotField
Dim pvtItem As Excel.PivotItem

Set pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Set pvtPageField = pvt.PageFields(1)
For Each pvtItem In pvtPageField.PivotItems
    pvtPageField.CurrentPage = pvtItem.Name
    'put your actual code here
    Debug.Print pvtItem.Name
Next pvtItem
End Sub
```

For more on programming pivot tables, take a look at [Debra Dalgleish's amazing site](http://www.contextures.com/tiptech.html#Go_P).